# What does "Let's face it, xxxx" mean?

Tags: idioms

I have a curiosity about "let's face it".
What does "Let's face it, xxxx" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an uncomfortable fact that you knew was true but you tried to avoid it, but can't avoid it anymore, you'd say

> Let's face it, *[fact]*.

For example, you and someone else were driving a car, and then the car broke down in the middle of nowhere. You're trying to get the car to start, but it obviously isn't working. After a while, you give up and say:

> Let's face it, this car isn't going to start.

It comes from "facing the facts". There are facts that you know are true, but you're trying to ignore them, so you've "turned your back against the facts". When you admit the facts, you're "turning around to face the facts". "Let's face it" means "Let's admit that these facts are true(even though we both knew it already)".

Answer (score 3):

It is something that you say before you say [something that is unpleasant but true](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/let-s-face-it_1)

> Let's face it, we both know why I stopped working there.

It is also used to mean "[face facts.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/face+it)"  For example,

> Let's face it, he was a big hunk of a man and a good-looking guy.

Comment: The reason it's used in that context is that it brings to mind the physical action of turning to look at (or confront) a sight or situation that is less than desirable, which you might otherwise wish to turn away from or ignore.

Comment: Is this some kind of suggestion? Let me know more example. And when do I use this senstence.

Comment: @user1917217 No, it is not a suggestion. It is said in the sense of: "It is what it is" or "face the facts as they really are."

Comment: @user1917217 You can also understand it in "get real" sense. Here http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+real

Answer (score 1):

It means to be honest about something that you might otherwise ignore and pretend isn't true.

If you turn your *face* towards something you can look at it. You are then confronting that 'something' and can deal with it.

The opposite of turning away from something.